# When exactly is the CSS of a component loaded/applied in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, loading

I have my app.js which imports `someComponent.js`. `someComponent.js` then imports `someStyles.css`. But `app.js` will only use/render `someComponent.js` when a button is clicked.

When exactly will the browser of the user now load and apply someStyles.css?
Will it be loaded right on loading the page no matter if the button was pressed or will it only request and load said CSS file when the component is actually rendered?

Comment: Is this standard create-react-app?  That uses webpack.

Comment: @zero298 yes exactly

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? The answer probably depends on how your app is bundled.

Comment: @isherwood I'm not having any problem and my react app is working fine. This is "just" a question for me to understand how react works and loads better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer this question, because it depends on how your application is setup and built. Your results may even differ when developing and when your application is deployed.

However, there are ways to verify this yourself using your browsers **developer tools**.

Every major browser has developer tools with a section about "Network" traffic.
If you open your developer tools onto the "Network"-tab and then refresh your page, you'll be able to see a chronological order in which resources are fetched from the server.

You could even apply some network throttling to see the effects in action on the page.

See:

- Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/#load
- Edge: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/network/#log-network-activity
- Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor#opening_the_network_monitor

[image: Log network activity]

You might also be interested in reading about [code-splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) as a way to change when components are loaded.